# Node.js socket.io handling Socket.IO Reconnect from Same Client

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have a Node.Js/Socket.IO server app that expects a single connection from a client app that runs on Android.  The Android client frequently drops the connection and then reconnects.  This is causing my server to have multiple pending connection and socket.io thread loops.    I would like to handle this from my Node.js server and close any pending connections when the client reconnects.
So my questions are:
How do I identify the source of the connection?
How do I detect that there are still open connections from the server to this client?
How do I close those so that there is only one active socket.Io?

Comment: socket.io should handle disconnecting "clean up", but that would trigger only if the client doesn't trigger reconnect event in a short period of time. Other than that you should have client to stop reconnection attempts after it loses connection. Maybe an internal counter when trigger events would do some trick.

Comment: Thanks Phoenix. Another way of solving my issue would be if I could handle any of the events that I see in my debug log:    debug - got disconnection packet
   info  - transport end by forced client disconnection
   debug - websocket writing 0::
   info  - transport end (booted)
   debug - set close timeout for client ZB6csEMfWPucHGr8FAvf
   debug - cleared close timeout for client ZB6csEMfWPucHGr8FAvf
   debug - cleared heartbeat interval for client ZB6csEMfWPucHG
   debug - discarding transport. My On('disconnect', function()) is never reached and I don't know how to handle the others.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example, that shows different aspects of what you are looking for :

**File : `server.js`**

```
//--- SERVE A DEMO CLIENT ---
const app = require('http').createServer(serveClient)
const fs = require('fs')
function serveClient(req,res){
 fs.readFile(__dirname+'/index.html',(err,data)=>{
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end(data);
 })
}
//--- SOCKET.IO LOGIC ---
const io = require('socket.io').listen(app)
var uniqueID = false //keep track of the unique client ID

io.sockets.on('connection',(socket)=>{
 //:Check if we have already a unique client connected
 if(uniqueID!=socket.id){
  console.log("[+] New Connection :",socket.id)
  if(uniqueID){
   console.log("[~] Disconnecting Old Client :",uniqueID)
   io.sockets.connected[uniqueID].disconnect() 
  }
  uniqueID = socket.id
 }
 //:Detect Client Disconnections
 socket.on('disconnect',()=>{
  console.log('[-] Disconnected :',socket.id)
  if(socket.id==uniqueID){uniqueID=false}
 })
 //:Output current list of connected client IDs
 console.log(Object.keys(io.sockets.connected))
})

app.listen(1337)
```

**File : `index.html`**

```
<html><head>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>var socket = io.connect()</script>
</head></html>
```